# Maven - Cucumber with TestNG. After starting cucumber test by tag - all testng tests @Test are started at same time with cucumber one

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, testng

in my project I'm using Maven+Cucumber+TestNG.

I have a test runner

```
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"io.qameta.allure.cucumber6jvm.AllureCucumber6Jvm",
            "rerun:target/rerun.txt"
    },
    features = "src/test/resources/Features/",
    glue = "Steps"
    )
public class RunCucumberTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
            return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

For daily runs on jenkins I use specific feature 'mvn clean test -s -Dcucumber.filter.tags="tag_from_feture_file"'. Everything works fine.

But, sometimes I need to execute small tests that are not included in Jenkins and they are written not in the feature file. for example :

```
   @Test
 public void Test(){
 <<code>>
 }
```

The issue is - when I'm pushing test with annotation(@Test) to master and trying to run any test from the feature file - all tests with @Test are starting in parallel with the cucumber test.

Please, give me advice on how to solve this(restructure project or some configuration changes).

P.S.

- @Test(enabled = false) - not the way how I want it to be;
- Instead of @Test => psvm - not the way how I want it to be;
- Move to another project all small tests - not the way how I want it to be;
- Write in the feature file and then declare everything in step class - not the way how I want it to be;

Is it possible to have Cucumber feature files and TestNG @Test in the same project so @Test won't start when I'm calling test by tag ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved. the solution was really easy(and I feel stupid) - https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

I've excluded the whole package at surefire configuration

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>my.package.with.tests.*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```